# How to get the output of groupby as below in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

After running groupby i got the result as

```
+--------------------+-----+
|                City|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|               Tyler|    2|
|           Fairbanks|    1|
|         Springfield|   12|
|          Charleston|    7|
|              Corona|    2|
```

I want the same result as below

```
Tyler : 2
Fairbanks : 1
Springfield : 12
```

I have to do it in scala spark.. not pysaprk

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit unclear. Please add more data like how your are printing the first output (putting the code will help). 
Rest, based on output I can think of you are just taking some values from RDD and printing on console with default println. If thats the case, try mapping the data based on your output requirement and then use .mkstring("\n") over it. So pseudo code will look like

`collectedResult.map(x=>s"${x._1} : ${x._2}").mkString("\n")`

Note: this is just an example may not run just like that in editor. Also if the size of result is too big, this approach is not at all recommended.

Comment: val df2 = findf.groupBy("City").count()
    df2.show(10)
I have used the above code to get the groupby values

Comment: First result i got by using  val df2 = findf.groupBy("City").count()
    df2.show(10)

Comment: Use `df2.take(10).map(x=>s"${x.get(0)} : ${x.get(1)}" ).foreach(println)` instead of plain show. It will take 10 elements from the dataframe, map it into our desired output syntax and print one by one.